# REST API call via Workbench giving Error

Tags: rest-api

I'm making a very simple API call via Rest Explorer in Workbench to Salesforce

```
/services/data/v49.0/query/?q=SELECT+AccountNumber+from+account+where+name=+'sForce'
```

and it is failing with error :

[image]

This is very surprising and I really think I'm doing something wrong or please let me know, if  is this is really some limitation.

Same query works, if filter using some other field say 'AccountNumber'

I tried searching Rest API developer guide/google but not able to find anything concrete. There are suggestions where one can't filter on Text area field etc.. but there is no information on 'Name' field.

Comment: Do you have encryption enabled?

Comment: When using Shield, there are additional restrictions which you can read about [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5). If you have probabilistic encryption on Account name this could cause what you see here.

Comment: Thanks both of you!! I enabled shield long back in my dev org and completely forgot about it